# Confused about this exercise question: if a set with a certain binary operation is a group

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I tried to answer the following exercise:

Let $S$ be a nonempty set with an associative operation that is left and right cancellative. Assume that for every $a$ in $S$ the set $\{a^n \mid n=1,2,3, \dots \} $ is finite. Must $S$ be a group?

My thoughts:

This is supposedly an old Putnam question so it's supposed to be at least moderately difficult.

But my solution seems very easy:

Consider any $a$ in $S$.

Then since $S$ is closed we have $a^k \in S$ for all $k \in \mathbb N_{>0}$. Since $\{a^n \mid n=1,2,3, \dots \} $ is finite every element has finite order that is, $a^n = e$ for some $n \in \mathbb N_{>0}$ where $n$ is the order of $a$. Let's denote the order of $a$ (the $a$ we are currently considering) by $n$. Then

$$e a^n \in S$$

is clear. Also,

$$e = a^n = a a^{n-1} $$

so $a^{-1} = a^{n-1} \in S$.

And now we are done: by assumption, $S$ is closed with respect to the opertion and we have just shown that $S$ contains the neutral element $e$ and the inverse of $a$.

> What am I missing?

Comment: Typically when one says "a set with an... operation", it is implying that the operation is closed.  In other words, it's saying that the operation is a function $\ast: S\times S\rightarrow S$.

Comment: How will you apply binary operation to a set with a single element?

Comment: @Hayden Ok, I will edit the question using this knowledge. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: You are assuming that an identity exists.  Consider the set of even integers under multiplication.  This is cancelative and associative but clearly not a group.  Oh, wait.  That's not finite.  Well, you can show $a^{n + 1} = a^m$ and so a right and left inverse exists but have to show they are equal.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're assuming the existence of the identity $e$ when you first state that every element has finite order.  We do not know a priori that an identity exists, and you need cancellation to prove this.

For example, if we didn't assume that the operation is left- and right-cancellative, then our set could be $\{0, 1\}$, with the operation of multiplication.  This is not a group.