# Let $S$ be a non-empty set with an associative, cancellative operation and for each $a\in S$, $\{a^n\}$ is finite, must S be a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The exact question is:

Let $S$ be a non-empty set with an associative operation that is left and right cancellative ($xy = xz$ implies $y = z$, and $yx = zx$ implies $y = z$). Assume that for every $a \in S$ the set $\{a^n : n \in \Bbb N \}$ is finite. Must $S$ be a group?

I am looking for a proof, which I can't seem to get.

Comment: What is $\bar 1+\bar 3$ in your first example? - Your second example fails to be cancellative

Comment: $\bar{1}+\bar{3} = \bar{0}$

Comment: And how is $\bar 0\in\{\bar 1,\bar 2,\bar 3\}$?

Comment: It isn't and so it is not a group

Comment: Back to the drawing board. If $S$ is a set, what is an operation?

Comment: Does the operation need to be closed?

Comment: My personal taste is that an operation is a map $S\times S\to S$.

Comment: @continental The second example is not a counterexample, because it's not cancellative: the zero matrix is strictly upper triangular. If you remove it, you don't have a semigroup (at least under the common meaning of the term, just like for the first example). Note that the product of two strictly upper triangular $2\times2$ matrices is the zero matrix.

Comment: Oh yes, I see, I didn't know the operation had to be closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused about this exercise question: if a set with a certain binary operation is a group](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1554361/confused-about-this-exercise-question-if-a-set-with-a-certain-binary-operation)

Comment: This question should _definitely_ not be closed as a duplicate of that question.  The question being asked there is different (it is "why doesn't this really simple argument work?", not "how do you solve the problem?"), and the one answer posted there does not answer the question asked here.  If you feel you must close one of the questions as a duplicate, you should close the other one (because if you think they are asking the same question, only this one has a complete answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As interesting and instructive it is to investigate your counter-examples and how one might possibly still save them - in the end this is futile because $S$ turns out to be a group after all:

Pick $a\in S$. As $\{\,a^n\mid n\in\Bbb N\,\}$ is finite, there are $n,m\in\Bbb N$ with $n<m$ and $a^n=a^m$. Pick such a pair $(n,m)$ with $n$ minimal. If $n>1$ then $a^n=a^1\cdot a^{n-1}$ and $a^m=a^1\cdot a^{m-1}$ hence by cancellation $a^{n-1}=a^{m-1}$ contradicting minimality of $n$. We conclude $a=a^m$ for some $m>1$. Define $e=a^{m-1}$.
Then $e$ is neutral for all of $S$: If $b\in S$ then 
$aeb=aa^{m-1}b=a^mb=ab$, hence by cancellation $eb=b$ and similarly $be=b$.
As for $a$, we find that $b^k=b$ for some $k>1$. Then $b^{k-1}b=b=eb$, hence by cancellation $b^{k-1}=e$; hence if $k>2$ then $b$ has $b^{k-2}$ as inverse. And if $k=2$ then $b=e$ is its own inverse.